# Runtime error '380' Could not set the Value property. Invalid property value

Tags: excel, vba, combobox, runtime-error

I have a combobox inside of page of multipage object in a userform.

Problem comes when code runs this statement:

```
'Trying to set the initial value
 userForm.comboBox.Value = "String"
```

Where "String" don't match with any of items of combo list.
I checked MatchRequired property and is set to False but the error still coming.

This works:

```
userForm.comboBox.Value = "Item_1"
```

Where Item_1 belongs to items list.

Error message is: "Runtime error '380'
Could not set the Value property. Invalid property value."

What I'm missing? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Apparently you are using `Style = fmStyleDropDownList`. Try `Style = fmStyleDropDownCombo`.

Comment: Didn't work @GSerg. Any other idea?

Comment: Did work for me. Please show your complete code.

Comment: It worked now! Thanks @GSerg!! I was changing the style in the form property but the code had the statement `userForm.comboBox.Style = fmStyleDropDownList`. That's why error was still there.

Comment: I didn't know the difference between `fmStyleDropDownList` and `fmStyleDropDownCombo`. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same kind of issue and i solve like the following Go to the properties window of the comboBox and try changing the Style to
0 - frmStyleDropDownCombo.

Hope this will Help.